# apt update error: Conflicting values set for option ALLOW_INSECURE regarding source <set> <unset>

Tags: apt, package-management

As subject, today when I tried to `apt update`, my ubuntu server throw error message that

```sh
E: Conflicting values set for option ALLOW_INSECURE regarding source <set> <unset> 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

How to detect what make this problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Please upload the output of `grep -r "deb" /etc/apt/ --include=*.list` to pastebin.

Comment: @N0rbert : https://pastebin.com/gfdifKgA

Comment: Try to remove extra space before `]` in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/FPT-docker.list .

Comment: @N0rbert thanks for your replies, I"ve removed that space, but the error still occur.

Comment: I've tried comment each line with `trusted=yes` and found that the error come from this line: `deb [trusted=yes arch=amd64] http://dn-repo.fsoft.com.vn/repository/docker-install/linux/ubuntu bionic stable` 
Dont know why, it works now

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove extra space before `]` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/FPT-docker.list` and check spelling in similar lines like with `[trusted=yes arch=amd64]`.

Comment: Ok, no problem.